# Extract characters between 2 dots in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a column in a dataframe that looks as such:

```
>head(df$col, 10)

"glut.AN02737.1.1" "glut.AN02737.1.2" "glut.AN02737.1.15" "glut.AN02737.2.1" "glut.AN02737.1.1" "gad.AN17896.1.9" "gad.AN17896.1.9" "gad.AN17896.1.9" "gad.AN17896.1.9" "gad.AN17896.1.9" "gad.AN17896.1.9"
```

I want to extract all characters after the first ".", and before the second ".".

So I want:

`"AN02737" "AN02737" "AN17896"`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One option can be:

```
#Data
text <- c("glut.AN02737.1.1","glut.AN02737.1.2","glut.AN02737.1.15",
          "glut.AN02737.2.1","glut.AN02737.1.1","gad.AN17896.1.9")
#Code
vec <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(text,'.',fixed=TRUE),function(x) x[[2]]))
```

Output:

```
[1] "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN17896"
```

Or more practical:

```
#Code2
vec <- sapply(strsplit(text, ".", fixed=TRUE), "[", 2)
```

Same output.

Answer (score 0):

Here are options

```
sub("^.*?[.](\\w+).*","\\1", string)
[1] "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN17896"

regmatches(string, regexpr("(?<=[.])\\w+", string, perl = TRUE))
[1] "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN17896"

read.table(text = string, sep='.', fill = TRUE)[,2]
[1] "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN17896"

stringr::str_extract(string, "(?<=[.])(\\w+)")
[1] "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN02737" "AN17896"
```

---

Data:

```
string <- c("glut.AN02737.1.1","glut.AN02737.1.2","glut.AN02737.1.15",
      "glut.AN02737.2.1","glut.AN02737.1.1","gad.AN17896.1.9")
```

Comment: Another option is `word` from `stringr` `word(string, 2, sep="\\.")`